# Small Wireless RGB LED Controller

Tags: led, wireless

We want to make a wearable accessory with at least one color-changing rgb led that you can set the color of by connecting to it wirelessly from a phone or computer. As this would be something to wear, we want to know what the smallest and least bulky setup to enable this possible would be.

[Something like this](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.bonanza.com/listings/DC-3-7V-12V-3A-Mini-Wireless-Remote-Control-Switch-LED-Lamp-Controller-433MH-/1521534711%3Fgoog_pla%3D1&opi=95576897&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwieiM379o6CAxX3QjABHSn6DcYQsDwI1gQ&usg=AOvVaw0R0AWi6BNrva6C1Fj7IP9_) fits the bill fine in terms of size and bulkiness, but it seems like it is tied specifically to that controller where we would want something that could connect through wifi or bluetooth, and we're not sure if it could control individual r, g, and b channels. Also, if possible we would want something cheaper.

We don't know very much at all about circutry so please keep your answers at a beginner level. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I have one of these that I use with batteries. If you use 4 Ni-MH batteries, you will get close to the 5V that the Addressable LEDs require. Four Alkaline batteries will produce 6V and you risk damaging the LED modules.

I connected a WS2812 LED strip. You can also buy individual WS2812 LEDs. Buy something on a little PWB so you won't have to solder to the tiny LED module.

Be sure to buy 5V LED strips/modules. You will need to either buy a mating barrel connector or cut off the connector and solder the wires to the battery/switch.

[image]

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIDChS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to EESE! As a beginner, you may be best off using ready-made modules that just require a few wires to be connected. You'll also benefit if examples of the required firmware (software that runs on the wearable microcontroller) are available. Finally, if you want wireless control from a smartphone (or computer) then Bluetooth Low Energy is a good choice for radio control technology.

Given the above requirements, I recommend you look at Adafruit's FLORA products. They are designed for wearables, offer Bluetooth radios as well as RGB LEDs. Example here from their website: https://www.adafruit.com/product/2487 Good luck!

[image: Product illustration from Adafruit website]